# Print out all article titles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to Python. Here are some lines of coding in Python to print out all article titles on http://www.nytimes.com/.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
   for story_heading in soup.find_all(class_="story-heading"):        
    if story_heading.a:
            print(story_heading.a.text.replace("\n", " ").strip())
        else:
            print(story_heading.contents[0].strip())
```

What do `.a` and `.text` mean?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's see what printing one `story_heading` alone gives us:

```
>>> story_heading
<h2 class="story-heading"><a href="https://www.nytimes.com/real-estate/mortgage-calculator">Mortgage Calculator</a></h2>
```

To extract **only** the `a` tag, we access it using `story_heading.a`:

```
>>> story_heading.a
<a href="https://www.nytimes.com/real-estate/mortgage-calculator">Mortgage Calculator</a>
```

To get only the **text** inside the tag itself, and not it's attributes, we use `.text`:

```
>>> story_heading.a.text
'Mortgage Calculator'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: what does the dot '.' mean?

Comment: In Python, and other Object Oriented Programming (OOP) languages, a dot is used to call a method from a certain class. For example, the built-in class `str`(string) has a method called `upper`, that converts all characters to uppercase, to call it, we do: `a = "this is a string"` and then `a.upper()`, or simply `"This is a string".upper()`. It seems you are really new to Python, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) has very good texts about it's syntax and methods of built-in class if you wish to go a little further with the topic.

Comment: Just a correction, writing without `()` in the end is not actually calling the method, instead it is just referencing the object associated with the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here,
.a gives you the first anchor tag
.text gives you the text within the tag